# The difference in ordering of enum type literals between PostgreSQL 9.0 and 9.1

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, jooq, postgresql-9.0

There has been some curious update in the way `enum` types work between PostgreSQL 9.0 and 9.1. The `pg_catalog.pg_enum` table has a new column `enumsortorder` in PostgreSQL 9.1. This order seems to override the previous enum ordering based on OIDs.

#### [PostgreSQL 9.0 Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-enum.html)

> The OIDs for a particular enum type are guaranteed to be ordered in the way the type should sort, but there is no guarantee about the ordering of OIDs of unrelated enum types.

#### [PostgreSQL 9.1 Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-enum.html)

> The OIDs for pg_enum rows follow a special rule: even-numbered OIDs are guaranteed to be ordered in the same way as the sort ordering of their enum type. That is, if two even OIDs belong to the same enum type, the smaller OID must have the smaller enumsortorder value. Odd-numbered OID values need bear no relationship to the sort order. This rule allows the enum comparison routines to avoid catalog lookups in many common cases. The routines that create and alter enum types attempt to assign even OIDs to enum values whenever possible.
>
> When an enum type is created, its members are assigned sort-order positions 1..n. But members added later might be given negative or fractional values of enumsortorder. The only requirement on these values is that they be correctly ordered and unique within each enum type.

#### My question

For the [jOOQ code generator](http://www.jooq.org), I'm reading the `pg_catalog.pg_enum` table, ordering enum literals by OID, the way it was specified in PostgreSQL 9.0. With the udpated specification, it seems that I *should* order the literals by `enumsortorder`, which seems to behave differently as it respects enum literal insertions "in the middle".

What's the most reliable, cross-version compatible way to read these enum literals from the `pg_catalog`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need to check the PostgreSQL version and change behaviour appropriately, or use SQL that doesn't touch the catalog to determine the ordering.

An idea for the latter, given dummy enum:

```
CREATE TYPE test_enum AS ENUM ('z','x','y');
ALTER TYPE test_enum ADD VALUE 'a' BEFORE 'x';
```

is to `ORDER BY` the cast of the enum label to values of the enum type using the `row_number` window function available in 8.4 and newer:

```
SELECT enumlabel, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY enumlabel::test_enum) AS sort_key
FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum
WHERE enumtypid = 'test_enum'::regtype;
```

This gets you the labels ordered by a sort key. In older Pg versions Pg will just sort by the `oid` of the enum values, in newer versions it'll use the enumsortorder, but you don't have to care either way, you've just told PostgreSQL "sort these into the correct order please".

Or if you just need them in the order the server expects, write:

```
SELECT enumlabel
FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum
WHERE enumtypid = 'test_enum'::regtype
ORDER BY enumlabel::test_enum
```

Comment: Ordering by the label is one option, but it might not be the one intended by the author of the DDL. I suspect there's no way to keep the ordering "as defined in DDL" compatible between 9.0 and 9.1?

Comment: @LukasEder You didn't notice the cast. It's not ordering by the label, it's ordering by the enum by *casting the label to the enum*. Edited to make that more obvious.

Comment: Awesome! (although a bit weird). True, I've missed the point of that cast. Thanks a lot

Comment: For future readers: It might be worth adding that this particular cast syntax didn't work in PostgreSQL 8.3 and maybe other PostgreSQL 8.x versions.

Comment: @LukasEder It's not just the syntax; it's that versions before 8.4 do not support window functions. Since versions before 8.4 are also obsolete and unsupported, I'm not fussed. Tweaked wording nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not fussed either :-). Still, noteworthy. This edge-case query seems to be quite different between PostgreSQL minor releases...

Comment: @LukasEder PostgreSQL has a quirky versioning scheme. 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, etc are *all different major releases* with different features. It's not "between minor releases" at all. I periodically beg `pgsql-hackers` to agree to change this versioning policy, but haven't got anywhere.

Comment: Wow, that is interesting! And it explains 1-2 things, thanks for the info! :-)