# Why order of results varies when querying table pg_enum in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, sql-order-by

Yesterday I queried PostgreSQL's [pg_enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-enum.html) table:

```
SELECT enumlabel FROM pg_enum
```

The `enumlabel`s were returned in the order of the `enumsortorder`.

Today I run the same query, but the `enumlabel`s were returned in the *alphabetical order* of the `enumlabel`.

What would have caused this to happen?

Comment: Did you or someone else, add/remove/modify enum values since your first query? Or  did the DB-admins install an update? Maybe [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398590/the-difference-in-ordering-of-enum-type-literals-between-postgresql-9-0-and-9-1) helps.

Answer (score 2):

Database tables represent *unordered* sets of rows. Unless you do specify an `order by` clause, there is no guarantee in which order rows will be returned, and the ordering of the results may not be consistent across subsequent executions of the same query.

So, add an `order by` clause to your query:

```
select enumlabel from pg_enum order by enumlabel
```

Comment: I was under the impression that in postgres the pg_enum labels were always returned in enum sortorder.  Is that not so

Comment: Obviously a misimpression. The sortorder is used to determine the relative position when compared. (<, =, >, etc).  I guess @GMB wasn't emphatic enough so: unless *order by* specified ordering is never guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks.  Just wondering why it would change after many months of behaving in the same way.

Comment: @MargaretKearney: I can actually change anytime, since it is not guaranteed. Just don't rely on an hypothetic default ordering; instead, get used to using `order by` whenever you want ordering.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GMB's answer, an attempt to explain the chabged behavior. I can think of some reasons:

- unbeknownst to you, the database was restored from a (logical) backup.
- Somebody ran `VACUUM (FULL)` or `CLUSTER` on the table.